# Set Metadata of .dll, .zip and .so files using php

Tags: php, dll, shared-libraries, metadata, archive

I'm having a hard time finding a solution to this problem.

I know via php $zip I have the possibility to set a comment for .zip files, but it's not exactly what I'd like to accomplish, as I'd like to edit the file's Meta Data instead.

Same goes for .dll or .so files (shared libraries), but in this case I didn't find any ways to alter the meta data, altough I know for sure dlls have metadata fields such as Copyright which can be edited, but I can't seem to find a way to do so via php.

So here's the only thing I was able to do via php (adding a comment to a zip file):

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $res = $zip->open($myfile, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if ($res === TRUE) {
    # Create the comment here
    $zip->setArchiveComment('my comment');
    $zip->close();
    }
```

About zip files, the ideal would be something like:

```
    $zip->setArchiveMetadata('copyright', 'example');
```

but this, obviously isn't going to work as php:zip doesn't come with such functionalities.

I wonder if there's a solution to my problem, thank you!